# Spotify iOS SDK Beta 5 build error

Tags: ios, sdk, spotify

I download the latest Spotify SDK from https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk. I tried opening in XCode 6 and build, but I get the error: could not read data from '...Simple Track Playback/Empty iOS SDK ProjectTests/Single Track PlaybackTests-Info.plist': The file “Single Track PlaybackTests-Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.

What's the solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed in Beta 6, but the solution is right there in the error message — the `Single Track PlaybackTests-Info.plist` file is missing. That's a typo - it should be `Simple Track PlaybackTests-Info.plist`. You can either rename the file on disk, or change the build setting to be correct.

Comment: I tried updating the building setting, but it gives me the same error. I wasn't able to find that file on disk so I couldn't try renaming it. What do you advise?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on the demo too... not completely done, but at just got past this error.
What I did:
* Create a folder "Empty iOS SDK ProjectTests" at the same level as the folder "Simple Track Playback"
* Copy/paste the .plist file from "Simple Track Playback" into "Empty iOS SDK ProjectTests"